# basic chemistry alkaline test for flavonoids!!! with reference please

Tags: reaction-mechanism

What is flavanoid physical and chemical properties, and how alkaline reagent test for flavonoids gives yellow coulour?

Comment: This is a homework question. Please share your thoughts towards a solution otherwise it will be closed in accordance with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but seriously? This really does look like homework to me. You can do a Google search with the exact words of your title to get highly relevant Google results coming on top (even despite the misspelling) I'm flagging for closure.

Comment: this is not  homework question. I have to submit a report for my lab work and i was tying to find this information but i couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

From this [reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=TXsiFVVuCqMC&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=flavonoid%20base&source=bl&ots=04L0QuwFfy&sig=xLpJ4o9VIclIybWO9IDeigYPCK8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SelpVay0JI7LogSfyIKgBQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=flavonoid%20base&f=false):

> Treatment of a flavonoid with a strong base will result in ionization of its hydroxyl groups with resulting large bathochromic shifts of both absorption maxima.